# Ostringstream different results

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems with my code, becouse it output two different results.

the code:

```
void output(int x){


for( int i = 0; i <=x; i++){


std::ostringstream ss;

std::string result;

ss << std::setw(5) << std::left <<  "Hi" << ' ' << "There " << i << "\n";

std::vector<char> s(result.c_str(), result.c_str() + result.size() + 1u);


result +=ss.str();


std::cout << result;

}



}
```

**output:**

Hello    There 0

Hello    There 1

Hello    There 2

Hello    There 3

which is right by calling it like: **output(3);** , but when i'm trying to define them inside a class and use it

inside the function things start to get very weird. The code i'm using using now is:

```
class myclass{


public:

std::ostringstream ss;

std::string result;


}v;



 void output(int x){


for( int i = 0; i <=x; i++){




v.ss << std::setw(5) << std::left <<  "Hi" << ' ' << "There " << i << "\n";

std::vector<char> s(v.result.c_str(), v.result.c_str() + v.result.size() + 1u);


v.result +=v.ss.str();


std::cout << v.result;

}



}
```

**it output:**

Hello There 0

Hello There 0

Hello There 0

Hello There 1

Hello There 0

Hello There 0

Hello There 1

Hello There 0

Hello There 1

Hello There 2

Hello There 0

Hello There 0

Hello There 1

Hello There 0

Hello There 1

Hello There 2

Hello There 0

Hello There 1

Hello There 2

Hello There 3

and that is wrong, how can i still define them inside a class and get the same output like in the first example?

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the first example your string stream is local to the loop. That means it gets destructed and created again on every iteration.

However on the second example this doesn't happen because the stream belongs to the class object v. And it lives as long as `v` lives. That means it will keep storing everything on every iteration.

To get the same result do this

```
v.result +=v.ss.str();
std::cout << v.result;
v.ss.str("");       // This will clear the string stream of v.
v.result = "";      // This will clear the string of v.
```

However I am not sure what you are trying to achieve because it looks a little pointless to do this.

Comment: That still don't answer my question on how to use class and get the same output like in first exaple

Comment: it says:  function does not take 1 arguments  and pointing to: v.result.c_str("");

Comment: it says:  'str' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'

Comment: I tried the edit, now it compile, but it output same as second example just less

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz I see. One more edit `v.result = "";`. This should fix it. But what exactly are trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm just trying to make things essy to change later :9

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function you get a new empty string and stringstream each time. When stored inside the class they are reused and accumulate output.

Nothing stops you from using local variables in the member function as well and get the same functionality as in the free function.